# Spark Scala update a dataframe via a method call

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to rename a list of columns in a spark dataframe. So I have written the below logic and it works fine when i run in spark shell .

But When I add to a static object and call via method its not working.

```
val policy1 = ("10931375", "TEMP", "US")
val policy2 = ("1328904", "TEAM", "US")
var policy = Seq(policy1, policy2).toDF("ID", "Source", "Country")

policy.show()

+--------+------+-------+
|      ID|Source|Country|
+--------+------+-------+
|10931375|  TEMP|     US|
| 1328904|  TEAM|     US|
+--------+------+-------+    

object Rules {
  val colMapping = Map("ID" -> "NEW_ID",
      "Source" -> "NEW_Source")


  def renameColumns(ds: Dataset[Row]): DataFrame = {
    colMapping foreach { x => ds.withColumnRenamed(x._1, x._2) }
    ds
  }
}

import Rules._
renameColumns(policy).show()
+--------+------+-------+
|      ID|Source|Country|
+--------+------+-------+
|10931375|  TEMP|     US|
| 1328904|  TEAM|     US|
+--------+------+-------+
```

But when i run in spark shell as below its working

```
colMapping foreach { x => policy = policy.withColumnRenamed(x._1, x._2) }
policy.show()

+--------+----------+-------+
|  NEW_ID|NEW_Source|Country|
+--------+----------+-------+
|10931375|      TEMP|     US|
| 1328904|      TEAM|     US|
+--------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are discarding the results. Don't use foreach

Try a fold

```
 def renameColumns(ds: Dataset[Row]): DataFrame = {
    colMapping.foldLeft(ds){
      case (d, (oldName, newName)) => {
        d.withColumnRenamed(oldName, newName)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

These snippets are not equivalent and shouldn't work the same way:

- In the first case you apply changes to a `Dataset`, with each call creating a new independent `Dataset` and immediately discard the result, and return original `Datset`.
- In the second case you modify a mutable reference to a `Dataset`.